# Android CPU Core Thread count

Tags: android, count, threadpool, cpu-cores

To get number of core we can use below line of code

```
int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

If device support hyper threading (HT) than

```
int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2;
```

Now, lets look AsyncTask stats for creating thread pool

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
```

I am not able to understand

1. Without hyper threading check how we can multiply by 2
2. And why +1

**EDIT**

```
private AtomicInteger mThreadCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
private final int MAX_THREAD_COUNT = 1950; //Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
private ThreadFactory mThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "KoreThread #" + mThreadCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};
private ExecutorService mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD_COUNT, mThreadFactory);

private void produceMaxThreadCountException() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        mExecutorService.execute(mRunnable);
        new Thread(mRunnable, "KoreThread #" + mThreadCount.getAndIncrement()).start();
    }
}
```

I checked the thresdhold in both cases

> ***Thread***
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try
> again
>
> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 21258 (KoreThread #206)
>
> After KoreThread #2058
>
> ***Thread Pool***
>
> allocate:394: Could not allocate a memory page for the
> adreno_pool_allocator.
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xb600822e in tid 9695
> (RenderThread)
>
> For thread count 1950

So we can create so many thread than why need of above calculation ?